# Inconsistent/Strange behavior of MySQL when using the group by clause and count() function

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Due to a bug(?) in MySQL the `COUNT()` function along with the `GROUP BY` clause can cause MySQL to leak out db details like the following -

```
mysql> select count(*), floor(rand()*2)x from users group by x;
```

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'group_key'

Sensitive details can be revealed here with a well crafted query. This
is unexpected behavior, maybe a bug?

```
mysql> select count(*), floor(rand()*2)x from users group by x;

+----------+---+  
| count(*) | x |  
+----------+---+  
| 8        | 0 |  
| 5        | 1 |  
+----------+---+
```

`2 rows in set (0.00 sec)` <-- Sometimes the query runs without any errors(Expected behavior)

Does anyone know what exactly causes the MySQL error.

The test bed that I am using is this excellent resource - https://github.com/Audi-1/sqli-labs

Comment: Can't comment on the behaviour, but re the error message - you want to hide those from any possible attackers either way. Don't show mySQL error messages in public facing apps.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I understand that. I just want to know from a pure MySQL point of view, why this happens.

Comment: It happens because MySQL is telling you what the error means. But a query can't produce that error. Updates produce that error.

Comment: @EJP If you run the same query, you will most likely get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a reported (and old!) bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081

> Description: A GROUP BY query returns this error under certain
>   circumstances:
>
> Duplicate entry '107374182410737418241' for key 'group_key'
>
> 'group_key' is not a real column name in the table. It looks like a
>   name for the grouping column in the temporary table.
>
> How to repeat: set names latin1; drop table if exists t1; create table
>   t1(a int) engine=myisam; insert into t1 values (0),(0),(1),(0),(0);
>   select count(*) from t1, t1 t2 group by insert('', t2.a,
>   t1.a,(@@global.max_binlog_size));
>
> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '107374182410737418241' for key
>   'group_key'

Comments indicate a suggested work around is to increase the available heap and temp table size:

> The workaround i found is to increase the size of the tmp_table:
>
> SET SESSION max_heap_table_size=536870912;  SET SESSION
>   tmp_table_size=536870912;
>
> now my request work !

Or to check your available disk space